# Kafka Streams Rebalancing Behavior

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I understand a rebalance can occur at any point and time on your stream.  When it does reprocessing of events can occur due to the latest offset not being committed for a given offset.

Does Kafka Streams allow any in flight processing finish before the rebalance occurs?  What I mean by this is your application is in the middle of consuming a record (inside your process method) a rebalance event occurs.  Does that processing immediately abort or allow the process method to finish?

A concrete example is

```
public void process(String key, String value) {
    String result = computeSomething(key,value) <---rebalance triggered here in time
    stateStore.put(key,result);
    context.forwared(key, result);
 }
```

Would the last computation ended up in the state store and be forwarded to the sink topic?  Therefore meaning when the rebalance completed the new partition would have last value in the store but still potentially "reprocess" that message off the topic?

Answer (score 2):

If a rebalance is triggered, the background heartbeat thread (of the underlying consumer) will only set a flag on the client. Processing will continue normally. After processing finished, `Consumer#poll()` will be called and the rebalance flag is evaluated. If the flag is set, all pending writes to state store and topics will be flushed, input topic offset will be committed, and afterward rebalancing will continue.

The only corner case is, if your processing takes longer that `max.poll.interval.ms` -- if `poll()` is not called before this timeout (e.g., your `process()` method takes longer), the application is considered "dead" and rebalancing will continue anyway. For this case, the next time `poll()` is called, the application would detect that it dropped out of the consumer group, and will rejoin the group, i.e., it will trigger a new rebalance.